# Spring + javax.persistence.Query: Manage type conversion from H2 and PosgreSQL DB native date types to OffsetDateTime

Tags: java, postgresql

For some reason I have to use javax.persistence.Query to execute PostgreSQL(real)/H2(test) DB queries, among which I have to get a field of datetime from DB. In Java it is OffsetDateTime type, with `columnDefinition="timestamp with time zone")`.

In testing it does not work because `getSingleResult()` returns `org.h2.api.TimestampWithTimeZone` that is not `OffsetDateTime`. But I think in PostgreSQL it must returns another type, which is native of PostgreSQL.

So how to manage this conversion in an elegant way? Must I use `Statement` to do JDBC queries? That seems too low-level. Or, is it better to change the datetime to `java.util.Date`?

Comment: Unless you post relevant excerpts from your code, I don't think you'll get help. (At least the JPA entity)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use this opensource project https://github.com/montrosesoftware/DbAssist/wiki. Since not much is clear from your question this is the best I can suggest.

Comment: Hi @yerqueri, thanks for your help. I finally decide to change the field into `Long` for that the date will be seconds since epoch in the final JSON. I think it is better to save the seconds in DB, then there is no need to convert the types anymore.